# flutter_map_tappable_polyline How would you go about highlighting or changing the color of a polyline on tap?

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I am using the flutter package flutter_map_tappable_polyline.  Does anyone have an idea on how I could use this package to change the stroke width or change the color of a polyline onTap and then revert to normal onMiss.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

The following code is mostly the original flutter_map_tappable_polyline default code.  Everything in it works.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_tappable_polyline/flutter_map_tappable_polyline.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

import 'data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(45.1313258, 5.5171205),
          zoom: 11.0,
        ),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
            urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),

          TappablePolylineLayer(
              // Will only render visible polylines, increasing performance
              polylineCulling: true,
              pointerDistanceTolerance: 20,
              polylines: [
                TaggedPolyline(
                  tag: taglist[0].tags,
                  points: getPoints(0),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  strokeWidth: 9.0,
                ),
                TaggedPolyline(
                  tag: taglist[1].tags,
                  points: getPoints(1),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  strokeWidth: 3.0,
                ),
                TaggedPolyline(
                  tag: taglist[2].tags,
                  points: getPoints(2),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  strokeWidth: 3.0,
                ),
              ],
              onTap: (polylines, tapPosition) { print(
                  polylines.map((polyline) => polyline.tag));
                },
              onMiss: (tapPosition) {
                print('No polyline was tapped at position ');
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Data.dart

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

final lines = [
  [
    [5.58213, 45.13065, 1005],
    [5.58209, 45.13078, 1004],
    [5.58186, 45.13091, 1003]
  ],
  [
    [5.47979, 45.14317, 1070],
    [5.47965, 45.14386, 1071],
    [5.47969, 45.1443, 1071]
  ],
  [
    [5.47269, 45.19369, 218],
    [5.4728, 45.19398, 217],
    [5.47306, 45.19414, 216]
  ]
];

List<LatLng> getPoints(int index) {
  return lines[index].map((e) {
    return LatLng(e[1] as double, e[0] as double);
  }).toList();
}


// I finally created a list of my own.  This works!  Invoke it by using taglist[index tag number].tags
class TheTags {
  String? tags;
  TheTags({this.tags});
}

List<TheTags>  taglist = [
  TheTags(tags:'Distance: 2.3km  Elevation Gain: 230m'),
  TheTags(tags:'Distance: 1.4km  Elevation Gain: 0m'),
  TheTags(tags:'Distance: 3.3km  Elevation Gain: 10m'),
];
```

I would like to highlight or change the color of a polyline when clicking on it but I am too much of a newbie to figure out such complex code.  I did spend a considerable amount of time googling and testing out ideas but nothing seems to work.  Thanks to who ever is kind enough to help.